# Find the successor & predecessor in a given array of integer values for a given integer

Tags: php

Let's say I have an array like that:

```
[12,3,4,5,8,9,11,20]
```

and a given number 7, then the predecessor/successor from the array would be 5/8 How do I find these numbers in an effective way?

At the moment I have the solution only for finding the successor via comparison.

Comment: Does your use case require to have both a predecessor and successor? Because if not, from your example case having "predecessor: NULL / successor: 12" would also be valid (I assumed it was not just a coma forgotten and you array can be not ordered)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your need to iterate over the array and compare every number, than save the number, if it is more close to your needle, than the old one:

```
function precessorAndSuccessor(array $numbers, int $needle){
    $pre = NULL;
    $suc = NULL;
    foreach($numbers as $number){
        if($number < $needle){
            if($pre === NULL || $pre < $number){
                $pre = $number;
            }
        }elseif($number > $needle){
            if($suc === NULL || $suc > $number){
                $suc = $number;
            }
        }
    }
    return [
        "predecessor" => $pre,
        "successsor" => $suc
    ];
}
``
```

Answer (score 0):

If you sort the array then just run through and check:

```
$num = 7;
$pre = $suc = false;
sort($array);

foreach($array as $v) {
    if($v < $num) { $pre = $v; }
    if($v > $num) { $suc = $v; break; }
}
```